# Can a cipher be shorter than the original text?

Tags: encryption, cryptography

I am reading the book "Serious Cryptography" by Jean-Philippe Aumasson and early on in the book there is a note which says:

"For some ciphers, the ciphertext is the same size as the plaintext; for some others, the ciphertext is slightly longer. However, ciphertexts can never be shorter than plaintexts."

This seems incorrect to me because I don't understand why a cipher can't also compress text that it is encrypting.  For example, I can create a cipher where every letter maps to 1 letter up in the alphabet, except the word "THE" maps to 1 and the word "IS" maps to 2.

Encrpying the text "The cat is old" will yield "1 dbu 2 pme" with this cipher, which is shorter than the original text.  Is there something I am missing?

Edit:  I would also like to restrict the plain text input I accept to only include letters.

Comment: That would be an encoding, not an encryption.  You need a codebook: "1 <=> THE; 2 <=> IS" as well as the encryption key.  You need to think of the size of the codebook as well as the size of the cyphertext.  Your "1 dbu 2 pme" is meaningless, or ambiguous, without the codebook.  A different codebook: "1 <=> A/AN; 2 <=> ISN'T" gives a different meaning: "A cat isn't old".

Comment: *Write programs that do one thing and do it well.*

If you have any specific use case, you could still use a compression algorithm, and then encrypt the compressed plaintext. The decompressor can work from the decrypted text, but not the other way around, because the Ciphertext will have very low entropy, that will not allow effective further compression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally encryption acts on input that cannot be compressed. It should be possible to input *any* kind of message. As most modern ciphers are bit/byte oriented that means that all possible messages of a certain bit/byte size are possible.

Note that a modern cipher should be IND-CPA secure. This means that any message of the same size should return ciphertext that is indistinguishable. If you have a specific set of messages that increases the ciphertext then obviously they are distinguishable from the other messages. And because of the pigeon hole principle, it is of course impossible to have smaller ciphertext for *all* possible messages.

It is possible to use a compression algorithm to compress specific types of messages in case *your* set of messages is smaller. However, you should keep in mind that the size of the resulting ciphertext may leak information to an adversary. Attacks on compressed audio streams or HTTPS connections are certainly not just a theoretic threat, they are all too practical.

And beware that even without compression, the ciphertext size will *always* leak information about the plaintext. Because of above, the plaintext must contain less information than can be encoded by the specific ciphertext size after all.